# Aweber API for C#

Tags: c#, desktop-application, aweber

I want to access my Aweber account details and my email list in a C# windows application.
So, please let me know how can I make it possible?

I got http://thecodenode.com/AweberCSharpNetSample.aspx but I am still waiting for the mail with source code.

Awaiting response.

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: I am new to Aweber. I am playing with this first time.The Aweber providing the API for PHP, Python and Ruby only (https://labs.aweber.com/) . I want a connection between Aweber and C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did write an entire .NET SDK for their API for Aweber, unfortunately they didn't accept it, hence it's locked away. As per our agreement they own the copyright for it so I can't release it.

They said they were going to go a different route, however their programming staff are mainly PHP programmers hence I don't know if they will.

I will contact them and see if it can be released.

**Update**

Yes it can be released. I have put the source code on Codeplex: https://aweber.codeplex.com/

It contains everything from OAuth and communicating with Lists, Accounts, Campaigns and Subscribers.

Only requirement is .NET 4.0, all OAuth and JSON code is self-contained.

Feels good to get the code out there to help other people, rather than locked away on my pc :)